# setting a div display property to block giving it fade effect

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous

I need to set the display property of div to block giving a fade effect,  fadein function does not change the display property of the div to block. So the div cant be seen. How can I do it?

```
$('lesson-'+tab).setStyle({
display: 'block'
});

<div id='lesson'>
</div>
```

Comment: Divs already have display:block. Why would you need to change it? Is there some other relevant code? And: No, the "display" property is not animatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can `FadeIn` an element whose property has been set to `{display:none}`

```
<div id='lesson'>
</div>
```

css:

```
#lesson{
    display:none;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lesson").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

demo link http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/TnHbJ/